# How can I conditionally render a container that's been outputted by PHP with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, vue.js

I've encountered a problem in which I get data from a database with PHP I then store the data into a PHP array like so :

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, name, description, experience, focus, fileformat, file, edit FROM trainers;");
$i = 0;
while($query_run = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $query_run['id'];
    $name = $query_run['name'];
    $description = $query_run['description'];
    $experience = $query_run['experience'];
    $focus = $query_run['focus'];
    $format = $query_run['fileformat'];
    $file = $query_run['file'];
    $edit = $query_run['edit'];
    $edit = explode(' ', $edit);
    $trainers_meta[$i] = array('Id' => $id, 'Name' => $name, 'Description' => $description, 'Experience' => $experience, 'Focus' => $focus, 'Fileformat' => $format, 'File' => $file, 'Edit' => $edit);
    $i++;
}
```

Afterwards I display the data from the array in the HTML code using a PHP foreach loop like so :

```
<div class="container-lg px-lg-4 px-0 pt-3 border-right border-left border-bottom border-radius-bottom mb-5">
    <?php foreach ($services_meta as $service):?>
        <div class="container-lg bg-dark-white py-3 px-3 my-3 border-radius">
            <form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-code-branch mr-3 ml-2 text-brand-primary" style="font-size: 1.9em"></i>
                        <h5 class="font-bolder text-truncate"><?php echo $service['Name']?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-8 d-flex align-items-center pt-lg-0 pt-md-3 pt-sm-2 pt-1">
                        <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pr-1">Úprava :</h6>
                        <h6 class="text-truncate"><?php echo $service['Edit'][0]?> <?php echo $service['Edit'][1]?></h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                        <button class="btn btn-brand-secondary font-bold px-22 py-2 mx-1" type="submit" name="services-submit-<?php echo $service['Id']?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-brand-primary font-bold px-3 py-2 mx-1" type="submit" name="services-delete-<?php echo $service['Id']?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12"><hr></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 justify-content-md-start justify-content-center pb-md-2 d-flex align-items-center pb-lg-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column pt-3">
                            <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1">Popis :</h6>
                            <textarea type="text" name="services-description-<?php echo $service['Id']?>" class="border-radius" cols="18" rows="4"><?php echo $service['Description']?></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 justify-content-md-start justify-content-center pb-md-2 d-flex pb-lg-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column pt-3">
                            <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1">Místo :</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="services-place-<?php echo $service['Id']?>" class="border-radius" value="<?php echo $service['Place']?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 justify-content-md-start justify-content-center pb-md-2 d-flex pb-lg-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column pt-3">
                            <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1">Termíny :</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="services-terms-<?php echo $service['Id']?>" class="border-radius" value="<?php echo implode($service['Terms'])?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 justify-content-md-start justify-content-center pb-md-2 d-flex align-items-center pb-lg-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column py-3">
                            <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1">Název :</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="services-name-<?php echo $service['Id']?>" class="border-radius" value="<?php echo $service['Name']?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

As you may've noticed I use the `Id` of the data row from the MySQLi database which it originates from to provide a unique `name` attribute which I can then use to filter through the `$_POST` of each of the containers so that I can provide functions like deleting from the database on a press of the button which is contained within each container. Here's an example of the delete function for a specific container :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $id = $trainer['Id'];
    foreach ($trainers_meta as $trainer){
        if(isset($_POST["trainers-delete-$id"])){
            $stmt = $db -> prepare("DELETE FROM trainers WHERE id = ?;");
            $stmt -> bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt -> execute();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply loop through each of the IDs from the database with `$_POST` and check which one has been set. This is important because the user also has the ability to add a new container and fill it with new data after they do so I have to check dynamically for the results from the database since they change overtime and I cannot simply hardcore a specific `name` attribute for use with `$_POST`.

My actual problem is that I am looking for a way to implement AJAX like functionality to the webpage so that immediatelly upon clicking delete for instance that specific containers disappears without the requirement for the user to refresh the page. I am trying to use Vue.js as my JavaScript library for the entire project.

Vue.js provides an option for conditional rendering with the `v-if` attribute that's provided in the page's HTML but my problem is that I seem to have no way of determining the variable that sets the visibility of the element to false because if I would simply add a `v-if` and then set the `trainersVisibility` variable in Vue.js JavaScript to false like :

```
let app = Vue.createApp({
    data: function(){
        return{
            vue_init: 'Vue initialization success',
            trainersVisibility: true //This would be set to false on the button click
        }
    }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

all the containers disappear instead of a specific one. I got an idea of simply echoing the `Id` from the results array with `v-if="trainersVisibility-<?php echo $trainer['Id']?>"` directly into the `v-if` attribute but that should throw an error because the base variable was never defined in the Vue.js JavaScript file at all and it's only occured in the PHP file within it's HTML code. I cannot simply define multiple `v-if` boolean variables for each container because I have no way of knowing how much containers with adequate data exist on the page since the number of them changes overtime. What can I do to use conditional rendering for each container sepparately for it to allow me to properly setup AJAX like functionality? I am very new to Vue.js so I'm very sorry if this is obvious to You but it's a little messy for me still. Huge thanks for any help with this issue from anybody!

Edit :

As per the comments of this question I was lead to the conclusion of converting the database array with the results into a JavaScript array and then do the rest with JavaScript only. That requires the use of the json_encode() function inside of PHP for later use in JavaScript. However `json_encode` was not completed properly. This was indded like I mentioned caused by the BLOB data that was contained within the array. The problem was that the BLOB data was converted to base64 only once it's been rendered in the HTML code where I used the PHP `base64_encode()`; function. And so now I convert to base64 directly in the PHP loop which stores the data into the array intially. Once converted to base64 BLOBs appear to be JavaScript compatible. The conversion now runs without errors and I can echo out the JSON array using PHP and it is indeed of a JSON format.

I've tried defining the variable inside of a  and set it to the JSON converted value as a JavaScript variable both in the included PHP file which scrapes the data from the MySQLi database as well as the index file itself. No matter the file I put the tag in or the position I put the tag in altough the variable exists Vue.js never sees it at all and so I'm unable to do anything with the saved data. I was trying to look for a solution but haven't found any way to parse a pure JavaScript variable to Vue.js. If there is any way this could be done I'm not aware of it. Guess I might have to switch to a completely different JavaScript framework just because of this...

Comment: Rather than using PHP to create the HTML, you'll probably be better off using PHP to create a JSON object that gets placed in the DOM (as a simple JS global variable), then your VueJS app can grab that JSON object and do the rendering of the data.
Your VueJS app can store that JSON blob in a state variable, so that when a user hits the delete button, as well as sending the appropriate AJAX request to the server, you can also update state by filtering out the ID of the element associated with the delete button that was pressed

Comment: I actually already tried that. I do the database to array scraping in a separate PHP file which I then `include_once` at the top of the page. Then at the end of the page I've tried adding a `<script>` tag like :

`let trainers_meta = <?php json_encode($trainers_meta)?>;
document.write(trainers_meta);`

Nonetheless the document.write is never executed and I get the following error output in the console :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'`

I haven't been able to found a clear reason for the error so far. Moving the `<script>` tag to the PHP file doesn't work either.

Comment: There should be no reason to call document.write. Simply leave `let trainers_meta` as you've demonstrated, then grab that variable (it should be available globally) when the VueJS app boots up. If you want to make the code even clearer, rather than doing `let trainers_meta`, you could simply set it as a property on `window`, like `window.trainers_meta = ...`, then it will be clear within the VueJS app that this data is coming from outside VueJS altogether

Comment: I  see, thanks for letting me know I'l try to use the variable directly then. The "file" array item within the key contains a MEDIUMBLOB string. Do you think that might cause an issue in the future when it's converted with json_encode to JSON?

Comment: The problem with `let trainers_meta = <?php json_encode($trainers_meta)?>;` is that you never actually output the response from the PHP function. You need to echo the output: `<?php echo json_encode($trainers_meta)?>;` (which most likely is the reason for the error you got). Always check the generated source when you get errors like that with data from PHP.

Comment: M. Eriksson not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean that $trainers_meta is undefined? Simply doing `<?php print_r($trainers_meta)?>` does print out the array with all of it's content so I don't think that it would not be defined.

Like I said there might be a problem with the "file" item from the array since it contains a very long string of MEDIUMBLOB junk which represents an image. JavaScript may not be able to put up with such an amount of data for a single array item?

Another issue that might be going on I think is that the 'Edit' item from the array contains another array split.

Comment: I never said anything about anything being undefined. `let foo = <?php json_encode($bar); ?>` will generate: `let foo = ;` (causing the syntax error you get) since _you don't echo/output the response_ of `json_encode($bar)`. You need to echo it: `let foo = <?php echo json_encode($bar) ?>;` - Notice the `echo`?

Comment: M. Eriksson you are right that the conversion to JSON fails. I've run a check with :

`if(json_encode($trainers_meta)){
    echo 'Successfully converted to JSON';
} else{
    echo "Conversion to JSON failed. \n";
    echo json_last_error_msg();
}`

Which returned :

`Conversion to JSON failed. Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`

I'm looking into that right now. Thank you for your help so far.